# Stomp over SockJS ActiveMQ relay to multiple servers

Tags: spring-websocket, stomp, activemq-artemis, sockjs

I'm trying to create a reasonable setup for client-client-communication for our existing infrastructure. I've been reading the docs for Spring, Websocket, STOMP, SockJS and ActiveMQ for over a week now and I'm not not sure whether what I am trying to do is feasible or sensible. Spring server and JavaScript client were up and running relatively quickly and sending messages between clients just works (direct connection from JS client to Spring server). This setup won't suffice for our needs so we decided to put dedicated brokers in between. Configuring ActiveMQ is a nightmare probably because I don't really know where to start. I have not worked with a dedicated broker so far.

**Environment**

- 170 independent servers (Tomcat, Spring, SockJS, STOMP)
- 2 ActiveMQ (Artemis) brokers (load balance, failure safety)
- a few thousand clients (JavaScript/.NET, SockJS, STOMP)

**Requirement**

I need every client to be able to talk to every other client. Every message has to be curated by one of the servers. I'd like the clients to connect to one of the ActiveMQ brokers. The ActiveMQ brokers would hold a single connection to every single server. The point is to avoid that all my clients would have to open 170 WebSocket connections to all the servers. The servers do not need to talk to each other (yet/necessarily) since they are independent with different responsibilities.

**Question**

Is ActiveMQ or any other dedicated broker viable as transparent proxy/relay i.e. can it handle this situation and are there ways to dynamically decide the correct recipients or should I go another route like rolling my own Spring-based relay?

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question. Maybe this is better. I just need a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a traditional messaging use-case (e.g. using ActiveMQ Artemis with STOMP) the broker manages "destinations" and any messages sent to those destinations. Messages are only dispatched to clients if the client specifically creates a consumer on a destination.

In your use-case all of your 170 "servers" would actually be messaging *clients*. They would need to create a consumer on the broker in order to receive messages. To be clear, once the consumer is created then the broker would dispatch messages to it as soon as they arrived.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "transparent," but if it means that the process(es) receiving the message(s) don't have to do *anything* then no message broker will handle your use-case.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. The thought never crossed my mind but you are completely right. My servers/controllers are now messaging clients and there is a broker in the middle. This works like a charm.